angular ng test throws error: Can't find stylesheet to import. @use "@styles" as *;
I'm using angular version 18 and when I run ng test to test some of my components, it ends with this error: Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Can't find stylesheet to import. @use "@styles" as *;
tsconfig.json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@enums/*": ["../../library/projects/library/src/enums/*"],
      "@models/*": ["../../library/projects/library/src/models/*"],
      "@dtos/*": ["../../library/projects/library/src/dtos/*"],
      "@styles": ["./src/styles.scss"],
      "@components/*": ["./src/app/components/*"]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}

tsconfig.spec.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}

component.scss
@use "@styles" as *;

ng-test result
> frontend@0.0.0 test
> ng test

✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

./src/app/components/accordion-item/accordion-item.component.scss?ngResource - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @use "@styles" as *;
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵

I expect ng test to work as expected, but sass-loader gives an error when I import a shortened file path in scss files. How can I fix this?

please share the tsconfig.spec.json
